# Implementing a StackOverflow type URL redirect

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect

I want to implement a `StackOverflow` type URL redirect over my website.
For e.g.

When you enter `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/` in the browser it automatically redirects you to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array`.

And even when you enter a scrap value in place of title such as `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/askl;fl;aksf` it will also redirect you to the right one based over the post number `11227809`.

Which type of redirect is this? Thats a `301` i know but how can I achieve this using .Net MVC?

I have seen a non MVC solution here [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292205/stackoverflow-like-url-routing) But need a MVC based one.
Thankyou.

---

`My Route:`

```
routes.MapRoute("QuestionUrlDetermine", "{qId}/{questionTitle}", new { controller = "Home", action = "QuestionUrlDetermine", questionTitle = UrlParameter.Optional }, new { qId = @"^\d{1,3}$" });
```

`Action:`

```
public ActionResult QuestionUrlDetermine (int qId)
{
    …
        return new RedirectResult(string.Format("/{0}/{1}", qId, questionTitle));
}
```

Comment: i can't find the original answer, but this is similar:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784979/mvc-routing-changing-routes

Comment: I have updated my question with the code please check.

Comment: similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248732/mvc-4-creating-slug-type-url

Answer (score 0):

You can have the last parameter optional and afterwards check in the Action where you open the question, if it matches the title of the question. If they don't match you can simply return a [RedirectResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.redirectresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) or [RedirectToRouteResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.redirecttorouteresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Comment: This says `404` when the route is not defined and when i define the route it gets into redirect loop, because after `RedirectResult` it hits the action against and again the route. I have updated my question with the code please check.

Comment: did you define another function with `public ActionResult QuestionUrlDetermine (int qId, string questionTitle)`? Having this without a `RedirectResult` should fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily be done using `RedirectResult`:

```
public ActionResult Question(int id)
{
    string title = GetFromDatabaseUsingQuestionId(id);
    return new RedirectResult(string.Format("/question/{0}/{1}", id, title));
}
```

Comment: This says `404` when the route is not defined and when i define the route it gets into redirect loop, because after `RedirectResult` it hits the action against and again the route.